# How locking work in MySQL with prefix of of composite key?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say Table T has columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G. and we have primary index as [A, B, C].
Table T has 100k records with value of A as x.

Could you please explain how below query will acquire lock - as in lock on all the rows with value of A=x? and which type of lock.

DELETE FROM T WHERE A=x LIMIT 100;

Comment: Do you want to explicitly get a lock during the transaction to prevent multiple operations running at the same time, or are you just concerned about which locks will happen when running that `DELETE`?

Comment: I'm just concerned about which locks will happen. Because when these queries are being executed some other request may arrive let's say DELETE FROM T WHERE A=x and B=y and C=z